# How do I link to a search view from the order?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I want to add a link on the order that points to a search in an unrelated model. I have a tree view like this:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view"
        id="sale_order_email_scheduled_tree">
  <field name="name">sale.order_email.collection.tree</field>
  <field name="model">sale.order_email.scheduled_email</field>
  <field name="type">tree</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Scheduled Emails"
          create="false">
      <field name="order_id"/>
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

And I want to link to it being searched such that `[('order_id', '=', 'order.id')]`. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: From where the order.id comes ?

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET I'm in a form view, so it's part of the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record id="res_partner_view_buttons" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">res.partner.view.buttons</field>
      <field name="model">res.partner</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[@name='buttons']" position="inside">
          <button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button"
                  type="action"
                  string="Test"
                  context="{'search_default_partner_id': active_id}"
                  name="%(action_open_scheduled_emails)d"
                  icon="fa-envelope-o">
            Scheduled Emails
          </button>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to link to another view and pass it a default filter using a `context`.

Probably you have a button that runs an Action.
Try this in the Actions's `context`:

```
{'search_default_order_id': active_id}
```

Comment: I roughly get what you're saying, though I tried using this method to link from the partner to my target, but I'm getting an access error. Any idea why?

Comment: It would help if you post the code you use for the "link".

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Ah nvm I figured it out.